# gcc 4.9 bug in structures initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc4.9

I have the code:

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    int b;
    const A a[2];
};

struct C {
    int c;
    const B b[2];
};

const C test = {0, {}};

int main()
{
    return test.c;
}
```

I have gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9.2. It can be compiled just fine with:

```
g++-4.9 -Wall test.cpp -o test
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test
g++-4.8 -Wall test.cpp -o test
```

However, it can't be compiled with:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Wall test.cpp -o test
```

And the compiler output is:

```
test.cpp:15:22: error: uninitialized const member ‘B::a’
 const C test = {0, {}};
                      ^
test.cpp:15:22: error: uninitialized const member ‘B::a’
```

Is this a bug or I just don't understand something?

Comment: Have you tried Cland or GCC 5?

Comment: @usr1234567 compiles without warnings in clang 3.5

Comment: And [compiles on GCC trunk](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bXwXkocS3OKbRzUA). Looks like a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49132

Comment: @T.C. please add that as an answer, if you don't want to rep then make it CW. As we have seen with many meta questions comments are not meant to stick around and I have seen important comments removed before. So important details do not belong in comments.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour SCNR :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that essentially reduces to GCC complaining about not-explicitly-initialized `const` data members in aggregate initialization. E.g.

```
struct {const int i;} bar = {};
```

[Fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b47f7fcb71c5925a) as there is no initializer-clause for `i` in `bar`'s initializer.  However, the standard specifies in `§8.5.1/7` that

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then **each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized** from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there
>   is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, **from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4)**.

Thus the code initializes `i` (as if by `= {}`), and GCCs complaint is incorrect.

In fact, this bug has already been reported four years ago as [**#49132**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49132), and is fixed in GCC 5.